# Assessing the quality of an image

Tags: images

I am looking for a program that can assess the quality of an image file. Quality as assessed by a human viewer. It's a bit subjective, but not so much.

Any OS, any license, any price, any file encoding is fine. Batch processing preferred.

Comment: Do you mean technical quality, or quality of artistic composition? Is [this](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-ZkJNLvuoopg/ULn5Frxdt6I/AAAAAAAADaQ/csfkNqPhQa4/s1600/robert-capa-war-photographer-d-day-landings-omaha-beach-normandy.jpg) a quality image? How about a program that would just look at the highest frequency, in order to determine the resolution of the image in the most-focused area?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul  technical quality. E.g., linked image is low quality ("hard to see well what's going on"). I guess this could be one approximation.